# Update sql base through html table

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have this table:

```
<table id="skuTable" role="grid">
    <thead>
        <th class="skuRow">Orden</th>
         <th class="skuRow">Maquina</th>
        <th>Fecha Fab.</th>
        <th class="skuRow">Norden</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Cliente</th>
        <th>Metros</th>
        <th>Tiempo</th>
        <th>Fecha Ent.</th>
        <th>Operario</th>
        <th class="skuRow">Editar</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

The SQL query:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT  Orden, FFab, N_Orden=Ordenes.OF_N_Orden, Color, Client, Metros, Tiempo, FEnt,Operario
        FROM ((
                Ordenes INNER JOIN VCLIENTE ON VCLIENTE.Clie_codigo = Ordenes.OF_Cod_Cli
            ) INNER JOIN ARTITTEC ON ARTITTEC.Tec_codigo = Ordenes.OF_Cod_Art
        ) 
        INNER JOIN VTiempos ON  VTiempos.Of_n_orden= Ordenes.OF_N_Orden 
            AND Vtiempos.OF_LIN =Ordenes.OF_Lin
        ORDER BY Orden asc, Fecha asc";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if ($stmt === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>
```

I print the results in a row and identify the 3 that I want to take to POST through the function

```
<tbody role="rowgroup"><tr data-uid="0bc4355b-a2b7-4cf6-9701-192e77ce6d1d" role="row">

    <?php foreach ($maquinas as $maquina): ?>
        <?php 
$cadena2 = $maquina['OF_Color1'];
$cadena = $maquina['Orden'];
$resultado = str_replace("999", " ", $cadena);
$resultado2 = str_replace("BLACK C", "BLACK ", $cadena2);
?>
            <td role="gridcell" class="sku_group" id="sku_group-<?php echo intval ($maquina['Orden'])?>"><span style="color: #ff0000"><strong><?php echo $resultado ?></strong></span></td> 
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['Fecha'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell" class="sku_maquina" id="sku_maquina-<?php echo intval ($maquina['Maquina'])?>"><?php echo $maquina['Maquina'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo utf8_encode ($maquina['Clie_nombre']);?></td>
            <td role="gridcell" class="group_id" align="center" id="group_id-<?php echo intval ($maquina['N_Orden'])?>" ><?php echo $maquina['N_Orden']; ?></form></td>
            <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo $maquina['Linea']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell" > <a target="_blank" href="https://clientes.ealbeniz.com/clientes/images/<?php echo $maquina['OF_Cod_Art'];?>.pdf"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Cod_Art']; ?></a></td>
            <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo utf8_encode( $maquina['OF_Descripcion']); ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['Cant'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['Metros']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo $maquina['OF_Tipo_Papel'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['Tec_Tip_stamp']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo $maquina['Tec_Ava_stamp'];?></td>
           <td role="gridcell" <?php echo ($maquina['repetido']) ? 'style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"' : ''; ?>><?php echo $maquina['Mag']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Cod_Troq']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Num_Tintas'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $resultado2 ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color2'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color3']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color4']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color5']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color6']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color7'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['OF_Color8']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['tIMER']; ?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $maquina['ESTADO'];?></td>
            <td role="gridcell"><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit"></td>
        </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </b>
        </font>

<?php



?>





 </tbody>
</table><div class="k-pager-wrap k-grid-pager k-widget k-floatwrap" data-role="pager"><span class="k-pager-info k-label"></span></div></div>
```

At the end of php, I add the following function that with the 3 data that must be sent by POST to update41.php to update the data:

```
// ----- Edit Row -----

$(document).on("click", "#skuTable .edit", function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
  });
  if ($this.val() === 'Edit') {
    $this.val('Save');
   if($this.id !== '.sku_group') {
        tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
   }
  } else {
    var isValid = true;
    var errors = '';
    $('#myDialogBox').empty();
    var elements = tds;
    if (tds.find('input').length > 0) {
      elements = tds.find('input');
    }
    var dict = {}; 
    elements.each(function (index, element) {
      var type = $(this).attr('class');
      var value = (element.tagName == 'INPUT') ? $(this).val() : $(this).text();
      console.log(type);
      // ----- Switch statement that provides validation for each table cell -----
      switch (type) {
        case "group_id":
              dict["Group_ID"] = value;
          break;
        case "sku_group":
              dict["SKU Group"] = value;
          break;
           case "sku_maquina":
              dict["SKU Maquina"] = value;
          break;
      }
    })
    if (isValid) {
        console.log(dict);
      $this.val('Edit');
      tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
      var request = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "update41.php",
          data: dict
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
            console.log("row updated");
          } else {
            console.log("row failed to updated");
            console.log(response);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);
          }
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // Log the error to the console
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {

        });
    } else {
      alert(errors);
    }
  }
});

</script>
```

update41.php:

```
<?php

  $Orden = $_POST['SKU Group'];
  $NOrden = $_POST['Group_ID'];
  $Maquina =$_POST['SKU Maquina'];



  $host="xxxxx"; 
  $dbName="xxxxx"; 
  $dbUser="xxxxx"; 
  $dbPass="xxxxx";

  $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);

  $sql = "UPDATE Ordenes SET OF_OrdenOFs = '$Orden' WHERE OF_N_Orden = '$NOrden'";

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  //$stmt->bindValue('[:SKU Group]', $SKU);
  //$stmt->bindValue(':Group_ID', $Group_ID)  
  $result = $stmt->execute();
  echo json_encode($result);
  if(!$result) {
      echo json_encode(sqlsrv_errors());
  }


   $sql2 = "UPDATE VTiempos SET Maquina = '$Maquina' WHERE Of_n_orden = '$NOrden'";

  $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
  //$stmt->bindValue('[:SKU Group]', $SKU);
  //$stmt->bindValue(':Group_ID', $Group_ID)  
  $result2 = $stmt2->execute();
  echo json_encode($result2);
  if(!$result2) {
      echo json_encode(sqlsrv_errors());
  }

?>
```

The following data appears in the console when pressing save:

```
sku_group
41prueba.php:459 undefined
41prueba.php:459 sku_maquina
41prueba.php:459 undefined
41prueba.php:459 group_id
2141prueba.php:459 undefined
41prueba.php:474 {SKU Group: "", SKU Maquina: "41", Group_ID: "129236"}
VM25655:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (41prueba.php:484)
    at c (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at k (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6)
(anonymous) @ 41prueba.php:484
c @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
fireWith @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
k @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6
r @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6
ajax @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ 41prueba.php:477
dispatch @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5
v.handle @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5
```

Here it is seen that it takes the fields, from the row in which I have pressed save to put the example of the console:

```
41prueba.php:474 {SKU Group: "", SKU Maquina: "41", Group_ID: "129236"}
```

I can't see why it doesn't pass the data to update41.php

Thank you very much and excuse my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `elements` variable is a collection of inputs, but your HTML might not have any inputs, except one button.

Also, if you want to pass arbitrary data via HTML, the standard way is with the `data-` attributes, for example, `data-type`. Passing it through something like class is very limiting (and unclear to anyone who reads the code).

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to do it correctly with my code? I am a little lost and I want to learn

Comment: There isn't enough information. For example, what exactly is `$maquina['Fecha']` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was that in this part of the function:

```
case "group_id":
              dict["Group_ID"] = value;
          break;
        case "sku_group":
              dict["SKU Group"] = value;
          break;
           case "sku_maquina":
              dict["SKU Maquina"] = value;
          break;
```

**SKU Maquina** and **SKU Group** did not have to be separated (No blank space).

The correct thing was (add _):

```
case "group_id":
              dict["Group_ID"] = value;
          break;
        case "sku_group":
              dict["SKU_Group"] = value;
          break;
           case "sku_maquina":
              dict["SKU_Maquina"] = value;
          break;
```

So in update41.php you have to put it the same:

```
$NOrden = $_POST['Group_ID'];

$Orden = $_POST['SKU_Group'];

$Maquina =$_POST['SKU_Maquina'];
```

Comment: I do not see a difference in your two code blocks.  Can you describe the difference, so that  us visitors can easily locate it? Also "They did not have to be separate." is not very descriptive.  What is "they"? and exactly what do you mean by "did not have to be separate"? Please `edit` to clarify, and help others learn from your post so they can apply this knowledge to issues in their own code.